# Какую переменную $_SERVER нельзя подделать?

Tags: php, переменные

Какую переменную $_SERVER нельзя подделать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe

Comment: только хотел схожий вопрос задать.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В вопросе не звучит главного - "кем подделать"?
Пройдемся по списку

`PHP_SELF`

имя скрипта, который исполняется. Думаю, вряд ли клиент его сможет подделать - он выставляется сервером.

`GATEWAY_INTERFACE`

также выставляется сервером. не подделаешь с клиента.

`SERVER_ADDR`

IP адрес сервера, на котором выполняется текущий скрипт - даже если его и подделают, то можно проверить.

`SERVER_NAME`

Имя хоста, на котором выполняется текущий скрипт. Если скрипт выполняется на виртуальном хосте, здесь будет содержатся имя, определенное для этого виртуального хоста.

`SERVER_SOFTWARE`

выставляется сервером. Клиент вряд ли подделает.

`SERVER_PROTOCOL`

клиент может выбирать способ, которым он отправляет запрос - get|post|другие. Можно ли это назвать подделкой... не знаю. Но клиент может вместо get отправить post.

`REQUEST_TIME`, `REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT`

выставляется сервером. Подделать можно, если часы на сервере переставить

`QUERY_STRING`
Строка запросов, если есть, с помощью которой была получена страница.

`DOCUMENT_ROOT`

клиент не подделает, сервер сам выставляет

`HTTP_ACCEPT`
`HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET`
`HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING`
`HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`
`HTTP_CONNECTION`
клиент может выставить что угодно в этих полях.

'HTTP_HOST'
Содержимое заголовка Host: из текущего запроса, если он есть.

`HTTP_REFERER`

самое популярное поле. Клиент может вписать туда что угодно.

`HTTP_USER_AGENT`

Часто клиенты это поле модифицируют, что бы получить нормальную страницу. Например, некоторые сайты для оперы выдают бредовую страницу, "мол у нас плохие дизайнеры и не осилили, установите ослика"

`HTTPS`

сервер выставляет. Но скрипту то все равно попадет декодированная страница.

`REMOTE_ADDR`, `REMOTE_HOST`, `REMOTE_PORT`

подделываются клиентом, если используются различные прокси, анонимайзеры.

`REMOTE_USER`, `REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER`
`PHP_AUTH_DIGEST`, `PHP_AUTH_USER`, `PHP_AUTH_PW`, `AUTH_TYPE`

вебсервер проверяет, как клиент аутентифицировался. Подделать клиент может только оправив имя-пароль другого пользователя или найдя дыру в вебсервере, который неверно проводит аутенфикацию.

`SCRIPT_FILENAME`

клиент может влиять, если скрипт запускается с консоли.

`SERVER_ADMIN`

выставляется с конфига вебсервера. Клиент вряд ли подделает.

`SERVER_PORT`

здесь процитирую справку:

> Порт на компьютере сервера, используемый веб-сервером для соединения. Для установок по умолчанию, значение будет '80'; используя SLL, например, это значение будет таким, какое сконфигурировано для соединений безопасного HTTP.
> Замечание: Чтобы получить физический (реальный) порт в Apache 2, необходимо установить UseCanonicalName = On и UseCanonicalPhysicalPort = On, иначе это значение может быть подменено и не вернуть реальной значение физического порта. Полагаться на это значение небезопасно в контексте приложений, требующих усиленной безопасности.

`SERVER_SIGNATURE`

клиент не подделает. А сервера часто подделывают, что бы обмануть хитрых клиентов.

`PATH_TRANSLATED`

актуальна для старых версий php

`SCRIPT_NAME`

путь к скрипту. Подделать можно, только если запросить другую страницу. Но какая это подделка?

`REQUEST_URI`

клиент явно указывает, какая это подделка?

`PATH_INFO`
`ORIG_PATH_INFO`

клиент то запрашивает страницу, поэтому изменяя url, может их "неявно" менять.

---

Но нужно помнить, что для скрипта все эти параметры выставляет вебсервер. А значит он может перекрутить практически все параметры.

Comment: Впечатляющий обзор!

Comment: Да , спасибо, всё разложили по полочкам. 
Хорошо бы этим обзором пополнить документацию по $_SEREVER , думаю многим полезно.